# Can I specify the x axis lablel in highchart?

Tags: highcharts, linechart

I am using highchart to do a line and area chart. The jsfiddle example is here: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/56/. `(My example)`

My data series start from for example 26/March/2013. But X axis draws the first label as May/2013.

Is it possible to tell Highchart to draw the first label as March/2013?

Many Thanks

Comment: Check your code line no 31 return curr_month + ' ' + curr_year; shows as May 2013. So the label starts from may 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that highcharts calculate "regular" interval between min/max values. In your case it will be problematic, so use the [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and return ticks between min/max values.

Comment: The problem is that my data series are dynamic. It is time data, may be 10 year or 1 month. As a result, how can I dynamically decide how many ticks I will need?

Comment: See the example form the docs, you can get min/max and calculate ticks by setting stating amount of ticks, then range will be calculated dynamically.